# multiple sql statement in a batch for mysql

Tags: mysql

i have to run multiple SQL statement in a batch
if i store those sql in a file 
and can i run that file for those sqls

thanks
J

Comment: Which database system do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!  [Using MySQL in batch mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the `mysql` client program for the purpose, see [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/batch-commands.html).